# Updating Data In Model Not Binds To Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I'm trying to follow [this pattern](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/04/24/modeling-data-and-state-in-your-angularjs-application/) in my application, however I cannot get it to work.

**CountriesModel.js**

```
app.service('CountriesModel', ['$http', 
function($http) {
    $http.get(baseUrl + 'api/countries').success(function(data) {
        this.countries = data;
    });
}]);
```

**UserCtrl.js**

```
app.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', 'CountriesModel',
    function($scope, CountriesModel) {
        $scope.CountriesModel = CountriesModel;
}]);
```

**user.html**

```
<select ng-options="country.iso2 as country.short_name for country in CountriesModel.countries" ng-model="selectedCountry"></select>
```

Now in AngularJs inspector plugin I can see that `countries` inside `CountriesModel` fetched properly but still `undefined` in `$scope.CountriesModel` inside `UserCtrl` and the `select` still empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that was pretty simple, but I've spent hours trying to solve it...

It's not AngularJs issue rather than JavaScript closure issue,

The following solved my problem,

```
app.service('CountriesModel', ['$http', 
function($http) {
    $http.get(baseUrl + 'api/countries').success(function(data) {
        this.countries = data;
    }.bind(this));
}]);
```